# What is the 'Debian way' of installing multiple MySQL instances on a single server?

Tags: mysql, debian

Do you know any 'Debian way' of setting up multiple MySQL instances on a single server? The server would receive data replicated from multiple remote databases.

I could use scripts like [mysqlsandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/) but I prefer to stick to Debian packages and would like to be able to upgrade the setup without much complications in the future. Another solution is [mysqlmanager](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mysqlmanager) - it works with MySQL 5.1 but it's deprecated and not released anymore with 5.5.

So what's the 'best practice' of running multiple MySQL instances on a single Debian server?

Comment: Nowadays docker can be used in such cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe it's as simple as running `mysqld_multi` and setting up your my.cnf correctly. `mysqld_multi` is a part of the mysql distribution - not a packaged frill.

There is [a patch](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617222#35) to make `/usr/share/mysql/mysqld_multi.server` appropriate for use in `/etc/init.d` and [another patch](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=637108#10) to make `mysqld_multi` use files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d`.

You can initialize MySQL data directories for new instances with the `mysql_install_db` command like this:

```
mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
```

Don't forget to change the root password of the newly created instance:

```
mysqladmin --port 3307 --user=root password 'new-password'
```

Comment: thanks; do you use it in practice? any horror stories/hints?

Comment: My horror story is a 2 days long data recovery because of debian's mysql init script was not shutting down gracefully the mysql because shutdown took too long. Since then i do not use debian mysql package, only Percona's binary distribution and the initscript in it

Comment: @GaborVincze - was it in mysqld_multi setup or 'regular' single-mysql-instance installation?

Comment: It was a regular installation. An 5.1

Comment: I do use mysqld_multi in practice. The hardest part is that you have to use mysqld_multi/mysqladmin to start/shut down the instances versus /etc/init.d/mysqld restart - there's not a terrible lot of pre-canned scripts that make it easy. Once you master it, it becomes old hat and is a very convenient way to spin up an instance for say, recovery, delayed replication - whatever.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian 8, you can use Systemd mechanism: no more need of `mysqld_multi`.

**NOTE:** I use MariaDB version! Not sure if it works with 'classic' MySQL package.

From `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@.service`:

> Multi instance version of mariadb. For if you run mutiple verions at once.
>   Also used for mariadb@bootstrap to bootstrap Galera.
>
> create config file /etc/mysql/conf.d/**my**{instancename}.cnf
>
> start as systemctl start mariadb@{instancename}.server

So, create a file `/etc/mysql/conf.d/myserver2.cnf`, and specify in it new pid/socket/datadir files and network port:

```
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-server2.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld-server2.sock
port        = 3307
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql-server2
tmpdir      = /tmp
```

---

**EDIT:** be carefull that first MySQL instance do not read this config file, with `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/*` at the bottom of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. If it is the case, replace the `!includedir` with a `!include` of each config file OTHER THAN myserver2.cnf:

```
#!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/*
!include /etc/mysql/conf.d/conf1.cnf
!include /etc/mysql/conf.d/confX.cnf
```

---

The MySQL official doc indicate you have to name `[mysqld]` as `[mysqld@server2]` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-systemd.html#systemd-multiple-mysql-instances) but this does not work with MariaDB. So just let `[mysqld]`.

Before starting the new daemon, don't forget to create the datadir and needed files :

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql-server2
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-server2
mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql-server2
```

Also reload systemd daemon config:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And if you want to start this daemon at boot:

```
systemctl enable mariadb@server2
```

To start it:

```
service mariadb@server2 start
```

Comment: The main (non-instanced) mysql reads `/etc/my.cnf`, that's why.

Comment: I edited my answer: in fact, it appears that the first instance DO read the server2.cnf file, with `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/*`. For better security, I included each `conf.d` file manually